# I need help creating constructors and returning boolean and strings

Tags: java, boolean

I need help fixing my code with the basic concepts listed above. To save from clutter, I took a screen shot of the directions here: https://imgur.com/SdiotUi

However, when I run my code it isn't working. I know there are a lot of errors but I'm having trouble fixing them even though I've spent the past few hours googling the correct way to do this.

When I create the first constructors I am not sure if I am assigning the name and legs correctly, I am having trouble returning "true", I get an error calling the parent class taking one argument, and I don't think I am overriding the abstract class correctly.

My code:

```
public class Animal1 {

    private String animalName;
    public int numberOfLegs;
    public Animal1(String name){
        name = animalName;
        name = "John";
    }
    public Animal1(String name, int legs){
        name = animalName;
        legs = numberOfLegs;
        name = "Jack";
        legs = 4;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return animalName;
    }

    public int getLegs(){
        return numberOfLegs;
    }

    public void isAMammal(){ 
        return true;
    }

    public void isCarnivorous(){
        return true;
    }

    public abstract class getHello{

    }
}

public class Cat1 extends Animal1{

    public Cat1(String name){
        Animal1.name;
    }

    public abstract class getHello{   
        return "Meow";
    }
}

public class Dog1 extends Animal1{

    public Dog1(String name){
        Animal1.name;
    }

    public abstract class getHello{
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well... several of your methods are declared as classes. Several of the proper methods are declared as void returns when they return something (boolean, etc). You are also trying to access Animal1.name in a static way instead of calling the super constructor super(name);. I'm sure there are a few I missed.

Comment: To point out the missing few, you're trying to assign to the parameter from the variable, and I'm sure your professor wouldn't approve of the class names. Also, Cat1's constructor doesn't seem to be of any use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class Animal1 { // If you want to have an abstract method, declare the class as abstract

    private final String animalName;
    private final int numberOfLegs; // better of using private and make it final since it's not going to change.

    public Animal1(final String name, final int legs){ //better making the input parameters final since they are not supposed to be changed
        //name = animalName; 
        //legs = numberOfLegs;//it assigned the field to an input parameter. that will take no effect on the object created.
        animalName = name;
        numberOfLegs = legs;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return animalName;
    }

    public int getLegs(){
        return numberOfLegs;
    }

    public boolean isAnimal(){ //boolean function needs a return type too!!
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCarnivorous(){
        return true;
    }

    public abstract String getHello(); // an abstract method has same requirement as a normal method besides the abstract modifier. it will need a return type. And it ends with a semicolon

}

public class Cat1 extends Animal1{

    public Cat1(final String name){
        super(name, 4); //use super to call parent constructor
    }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){   
        return "Meow";
    }
}

public class Dog1 extends Animal1{

    public Dog1(final String name){
        super(name, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHello(){
        return "Woof";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like a few of your methods are declared as classes. I assume you wanted to make them abstract methods. They need to be changed to:

```
public abstract String getHello();
```

Note that abstract methods can only be declared in an abstract class. So, you need to redefine Animal1 as abstract.

```
public abstract class Animal1
```

Next, when you implement the abstract method, you define it as

```
public String getHello()
```

If you are using an IDE like Eclipse it will automatically offer to generate this method.

Finally, when using your constructor in your child classes like Cat1, you are trying to set "name" as if it was a static variable and bypassing the constructor you already had set for Animal1. The best way to correct this is to change the constructor in Cat1 and Dog1 to call the super constructor.

```
public Cat1(String name){
    super(name);
}
```

Comment: Change the getHello method in Animal1 to the "public abstract String getHello()" and change the Animal1 class as I said above to indicate it can be extended. My suggestions comply with the instructions provided.

Comment: I just tested your code with my suggestions and apart from 2 methods that return void when they should be boolean, it works fine. Are you sure you put each class in their own file name after the class? Example: Animal1 in Animal1.java?